# Debugging Datastructures Visually

Tags: java, data-structures, visualization

I've got some Java code which builds a data structure (approx 500 small interlinked objects) from data in some files and I'd really like to visualise the resulting structure. I hope that seeing it will allow me to optimise, not the code, but the data itself.

I'm wondering if there is a debugger that will do this or perhaps a way I can dump the data and have a tool build me a pretty graph of the data structure.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this before by dumping all my objects to Dot format, for [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), and then used GraphViz to visualize the data, but not in real time. I had a command that would start a dump visitor that would walk the structure. Anyways it was about a second to dump and a few more to balance the graph when working with about 3000 nodes.

Comment: Edit: added a link to the GraphViz webpage, so I can now delete my own answer which is otherwise a duplicate.

Comment: thanks! I answered from my phone, so iphone so I couldn't copy&paste.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the tool I've used for doing something similar is the GNU Data Display Debugger [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).  According to the manual, you can use JDB as the debugging backend.  I've never tried it, but it might be worth a shot -- I had great success using DDD to create graphs of the complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

On the heavy-weight side of things, there is the software reengineering collection called Moose. It has everything you need for this. But it is a large set of separate tools (developed by students mostly), with a varying level of maturity and ease-of-use.

http://moose.unibe.ch/

Answer (score 0):

Other tools to visualize data in Java: [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) and [Processing](http://processing.org/).